# What would cause the "time" picker to display an hour that is different in the selector

Tags: codenameone, picker

When set the initial time is set for after 12 noon the value on the display and the selector match. When it is set before 12 noon the display is one hour greater than what the selector shows(which is the correct value).

What do I need to do differently?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you do this in code? What's your timezone? On which device type/OS version?

Comment: String text = "09:30"; // 24 hour format or "21:30" for pm
int iHour = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(0, 2));
int iMinute = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(3, 5));
picker.setTime(iHour, iMinute);
Android, time zone is not to be considered.

Comment: The timezone might be the reason for the discrepancy between the native and Codename One version. I'm assuming 9:30 appears correctly in the UI but when you click the button on the device the hour UI appears? Which version of Android? Did you try more than one device?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Actually it is the other way around. The UI shows 10:30 AM, but in the selector it shows the correct 9:30 AM, while the 9:30 PM shows correctly in both UI and selector. This happens on Android 6.0. I'll load it on a 4.04, 4.1.2 and then on an iPhone 4s and 6plus.

Comment: It shows up in the simulator too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
Form hi = new Form("Picker", BoxLayout.y());
String text = "09:30"; 
// 24 hour format or "21:30" for pm 
int iHour = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(0, 2)); 
int iMinute = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(3, 5)); 
Picker picker= new Picker();
picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
picker.setTime(iHour, iMinute);         
hi.add(picker);
hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: The only difference is that I have picker.setShowMeridiem(true); I guess that should be false.

Comment: I set the setShowMeridiem to false, and I get what you get, but the 9:30 pm shows as 21:30.

Comment: When setShowMeridiem is true the selector (the scrollable wheel) shows 9:30, but the text display on the screen shows 10:30am. I'd post screen shots but I don't know how to add them to comments

Comment: The problem is in line 326 of Picker.java

`
[PICKER]
316: value = 540
317: hour = 9
318: minute = 0
319: showMeridiem = true
321: hour >= 12 false
324: text = "am";
326: setText(twoDigits(hour % 13 + 1) + ":" + twoDigits(minute) + text);

 238: twoDigits(int i = 10) {
 242: return "10";

 238: twoDigits(int i = 0) {
 242: return "01";



[LABEL]
219: public void setText(String text = "10:00am"){

`

Answer (score 1):

```
Changing Picker.java line 326
original: setText(twoDigits(hour % 13 + 1) + ":" + twoDigits(minute) + text);
solution: setText(twoDigits(hour <= 12 ? hour : hour - 12) + ":" + twoDigits(minute) + text);

fixes the showMeridiem problem for am hours.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is a work around to the problem

picker = new Picker() {

    protected String twoDigits(int i) {
        if(i < 10) {
            return "0" + i;
        }
        return "" + i;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateValue() {
        if (getFormatter() != null) {
            setText(getFormatter().format(getDate()));
            return;
        }
        switch (pickerType) {
            case Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS:
                setText(getSelectedString());
                break;
            case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE:
                setText(L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateShortStyle(getDate()));
                break;
            case Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME:
                try {
                    int v = getTime();
                    int hour = v / 60;
                    int minute = v % 60;
                    if (showMeridiem) {
                        String text;
                        if (hour >= 12) {
                            text = "pm";
                        } else {
                             text = "am";
                        }
                        setText(twoDigits(hour <= 12 ? hour : hour - 12, 2) + ":" +  twoDigits(minute) + text));
                    } else {
                        setText(twoDigits(hour) + ":" + twoDigits(minute));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                break;
            case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE_AND_TIME:
                setText(L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateTimeShort(getDate()));
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```